# Access Query without VBA

Tags: ms-access

I have a question regarding a database query on unrelated tables.
It is required that VBA isn't used this time (requirement from my manager), which makes it hard.

My query must return 5 columns of data. 
The first 4 columns are directly retrieved from the Output of a previous query, so that is easy.

```
Query Q_STOP_LOSS: 

Year  Contr_Pool_ID          Contr_Ins_ID      COUNTRY   Employees    STOP_LOSS
2010  Crédit Agricole CIB    QUATREM           2         6024
2010  Crédit Agricole CIB    QUATREM           2         6024
2010  Amada CO LTD           MALAKOFF MEDERIC  4         1320
2010  Amada CO LTD           MALAKOFF MEDERIC  4         1320
2010  Amada CO LTD           MALAKOFF MEDERIC  4         1320
```

The last column called "STOP_LOSS" is the problem because the value filled in there should be retrieved from an unrelated table based on a WHERE clause. 
It should contain the SL value from another table that does not contain equal fields. 
The table is called T_STOP_LOSS and lists intervals.

```
Table: T_STOP_LOSS

ID   LIVES_FROM LIVES_TO  NR_COUNTRIES_FROM  NR_COUNTRIES_TO  SL_VALUE
1    0          999       2                  2                39,3
12   0          999       3                  3                34,6
23   0          999       4                  4                29,6
34   0          999       5                  9                25,7
45   0          999       10                 100              22,17
46   1000       1499      2                  2                31,1
2    1000       1499      3                  3                27,4
13   1000       1499      4                  4                23,3
24   1000       1499      5                  9                20,4
35   1000       1499      10                 100              17,5
```

When the values for "Country" and "Employees" (columns 3 & 4, being the results of previous queries) lie in the interval between respectively "LIVES_FROM/LIVES_TO" AND "NR_COUNTRIES_FROM/NR_COUNTRIES_TO", then what should be returned needs to be the corresponding SL_Value. I can't figure it out since there are no corresponding fields between the two tables and I'm not allowed to use VBA this time. 
To make it harder, "LIVES_FROM/LIVES_TO" and "NR_COUNTRIES_FROM/NR_COUNTRIES_TO" contain the ID of a related table.
Any idea how I can get add this column to the query without using VBA... ? 
I attempted to use the Query tool and also SQL view, but I was unable to achieve a proper result (with VBA it would be a lot easier and I am not the most handy one with Access on its own...).

Let me know when my question is not clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 sl_value
        FROM   t_stop_loss t
        WHERE  q.country BETWEEN nr_countries_from AND nr_countries_to
               AND q.employees BETWEEN lives_from AND lives_to) AS stop_loss,
       q.year,
       q.contr_pool_id,
       q.contr_ins_id,
       q.country,
       q.employees
FROM   q_stop_loss q
```

Comment: I'll check tomorrow, still no internet, only 3g :-/

Comment: That's awesome Remou, I've learned a lot again from this query.